# In order to program a SBC is it necessary to learn the complete Linux?

Tags: sbc

I want to build applications and GUI's in SBC's. Since almost all SBC's run on Linux OS. for me as a programmer, is it necessary to learn complete linux and kernal of that SOC/SBC? or with application programming experience can I write programs to any embedded processors(code portability)?

Comment: Of course not. Only enough to write the program you want with a framework/toolkit/libraries you need. You don't necessarily even need to know your program is running on Linux as there are several multiplatform frameworks you can use to build applications. But this is not an electrical engineering question.

Comment: Literally *no one* knows the *complete* Linux. And for writing applications, only very basic knowledge would be needed. Just get started and learn as you go, when you need to know something, learn that.

Comment: If you know how to write a web page, you’re halfway there.apart from being able to load apps and navigate linux, you can do just about everything in javascript.